# z-index vs <object> : is there any reason why this doesnt work on majors browser? (except Firefox)

Tags: html, css, flash, youtube

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3eDSR/2/) code :

## HTML

```
<div class="box_video">
    <object width="330" height="290" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/KEkR1ox_K10?version=3&amp;f=user_uploads&amp;app=youtube_gdata&amp;rel=1&amp;border=0&amp;fs=1&amp;autoplay=0" style="visibility: visible;"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /></object>
</div>

<div class="box_fixed">
    My Text
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.box_video 
{
    z-index: 20;
    height=400;
    background-color: #FF0000;   
    position:relative; 
}

.box_fixed {
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    bottom: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 40;
}
```

now, what I'd like to aspect is that the `fixed` div should be `over` the video (z-index of `box_fixed` is higher than `box_video`).

But in fact (expect Firefox) on IE/Chrome (for example) it is under.

Where am I wrong? Is there any special `<object>` attribute to care about?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One thing to try which usually works is to set the param:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

in the object tag.

e.g.

```
<object width="330" height="290" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/KEkR1ox_K10?version=3&amp;f=user_uploads&amp;app=youtube_gdata&amp;rel=1&amp;border=0&amp;fs=1&amp;autoplay=0" style="visibility: visible;">
   <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
   <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I link a video using **embed** tag inside a **object** tag, and this solution doesn't work.

Comment: is the 2nd param meant to not be closed?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set `wmode` to `transparent`.

Answer (score 3):

`z-index` will not work on tags that are not positioned as `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`.

So in your css,

```
object {
    position: relative; // or absolute or fixed
    z-index: 1; // this will work, so you can do any overlay over this object
}
```